# Case Comment component missing in Force.com IDE

Tags: case, metadata, eclipse, force.com-ide

I just installed the Force.com IDE because I needed to search my Apex code and workflow rules (which you're unable to do in Salesforce).

I noticed the Case Comment workflow component isn't being synced to my machine.  How do I bring down the Case Comment data so I can search on it?

[image: Case Comment is missing]

Comment: Can you share the content of your `package.xml` file?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'd prefer not to share the entire content of that file.  Is there a specific element(s) you would like me to look for?

Comment: I think specifically the `Flow` section.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to manually edit your `package.xml` file and use wildcard characters. The `Flow`* and `Workflow` types are what you're interested in here. I'm not using `Eclipse` personally, but I think ensuring it contains this snippet should work (parent tags shown so you can see where to put it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

See also:

- [Full List of All Accessible Types Through Metadata Api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/full-list-of-all-accessible-types-through-metadata-api)
- [Workflow (Metadata API Developer Guide)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm)
- [Flow (Metadata API Developer Guide)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm)
- [Sample package.xml Manifest Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm?search_text=wildcard)

* <sub><sup>The Flow type will get you Visual Workflows and Process Builder, which might also be relevant here</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I checked my `packages.xml` file and I already have the wildcard `Flow` and `Workflow` sections that you posted (version 36.0 instead of 37.0, but I'm guessing that's not the culprit).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will sync many metadata types, but not all of them.  Please use the Force.com Migration Tool for access to all entities.

Comment: Probably worth adding a little more detail here.